# innerHTML modifying whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got an unexpected behavior from my Javascript code. I'm creating a line of table with `document.createElement("tr")` and an **array of cells** with that code:
`cellule = new Array(3).fill(document.createElement("td"));`

But when I'm filling it with my values using *innerHTML* property case by case, the whole array is modified. Here is full code:

```
ligne = document.createElement("tr");;
cellule = new Array(3).fill(document.createElement("td"));

cellule[0].innerHTML = "Chat";
cellule[1].innerHTML = "Chien";
cellule[2].innerHTML = "Alligator";

ligne.appendChild(cellule[0]);
ligne.appendChild(cellule[1]);
ligne.appendChild(cellule[2]);
maTable.appendChild(ligne);
```

Results are :

```
cellule[0] => "Alligator"
cellule[1] => "Alligator"
cellule[2] => "Alligator"
```

Why is my whole array filled with the last innerHTML used?

Comment: Because you only have one single `td` element here. You stuffed three references to the element into your array, but it is still only one element.

Comment: `new Array(3).fill(document.createElement("td"));` you add *a single* `<td>` element in three different positions in one array.

Comment: @VLAZ ooh, interristing, should I loop on my array to fill it case by case?

Comment: I did filling it by looping on it and it works, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 'filll' was used, the same td was copied, causing an issue. One way is to create an independent td.

```
ligne = document.createElement("tr");
var datas = ['Chat', 'Chien', 'Alligator'];
for(var i=0; i<datas.length; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = datas[i];
    ligne.appendChild(td);
}

maTable.appendChild(ligne);
```

Comment: Hey HolyMoly, thanks for your answer. Please make sure that you explain why this is working compared to his solution. The fact that he has been hardcoding it has nothing to do with the actual problem. The fact that you are creating a new TD for each "data" is.

Answer (score 1):

[`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Examples) add the same element (with the same reference) into your array.

You can put your elements with another way, like

```
cellule = [];
for (let i = 3; i--;) {
  cellule.push(document.createElement("td"));
}
```

or

```
cellule = new Array(3);
for (let i = cellule.length; i--;) {
  cellule[i] = document.createElement("td");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work - `cellule` is a sparse array, so `.map` will skip the empty positions. You end up with an array with 3 empty positions again.

Comment: `cellule.fill(0).map(() => document.createElement("td"));`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with:

```
cellule = new Array(3).fill(document.createElement("td"));
```

Here you are creating an array with 3 of the same `td` elements. So when you change the one at index `0`, you are also changing the one at index `1` and `2` as you are referencing the same element in memory.

An easy way to fix this is to manually create an array using a for loop and pushing unique references of the element into your `cellule` array.

See example below:

```js
var maTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
var ligne = document.createElement("tr");;

var cellule = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  cellule.push(document.createElement("td"));
}

cellule[0].textContent = "Chat"; // use textContent instead of innerHTML if only adding text
cellule[1].textContent = "Chien";
cellule[2].textContent = "Alligator";

ligne.appendChild(cellule[0]);
ligne.appendChild(cellule[1]);
ligne.appendChild(cellule[2]);
maTable.appendChild(ligne);
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When fill gets passed an object, it will copy the reference and fill
>   the array with references to that object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Description

Here is one of the way you could achieve the same.

```js
    cellule = new Array(3).fill("")
    cellule.forEach((el,index) => cellule[index] = document.createElement("td"))
    cellule[0].textContent = "Chat"; 
    cellule[1].textContent = "Chien";
    cellule[2].textContent = "Alligator";
    console.log(cellule[0].textContent);
    console.log(cellule[1].textContent);
    console.log(cellule[2].textContent);
```