# How to add multiple cells using createelement?

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

I am trying to add 4 columns table using createElement.
I'm not sure if I have to assign 4 variables to create 'td' element for 4 cells, or I would need just one.

```
let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
let DesCell = document.createElement('td');
let desText = document.createTextNode(description);
let typeCell = document.createElement('td');
let typeText = document.createTextNode(type);
let amountCell = document.createElement('td');
let amountText = document.createTextNode(amount);
let toolCell = document.createElement('td');
let toolText = document.createTextNode(tool);
```

I didn't add appendchild property yet. So please ignore that.
it seems too long, so I'm not sure if i'm doing this in efficiency way.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerHTML modifying whole array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489598/innerhtml-modifying-whole-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertCell method

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="table1"></table>
    <script>
function createCell() {
    var table = document.getElementById('table1');
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
createCell();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would there be a way using createelement ?

Comment: You can use loop so that you do not need to create 4 different variables otherwise there is no way